# Alert Dialog not popping right. Button causing exception. Unsure why

Tags: android, button, dialog, alert

Nearly everything works in a program I've been working on. As I make changes in the `UI`, everything is set correctly. For reasons I can't figure out, when I hit the enter button of my main `UI` the app force closes with an exception. From the log...

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method enterMood(View) in the activity class com.loch.meaptracker.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'enterButtonID'

Here's the program code. Eclipse doesn't flag anything for either errors or warnings. I'm at a bit of a loss and pretty burnt out looking at this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.loch.meaptracker;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar happyBar, energyBar, anxietyBar, painBar;
private EditText noteField;
private DatePicker dPick;
private TimePicker tPick;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button enterButton;
private int happyValue = 4, energyValue = 4, anxietyValue = 4,
        painValue = 4;
private static final String TAG = "heapApp";
private String Mood = "Blah";
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // bars
        happyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.happinessBarID);
        happyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        energyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.energyBarID);
        energyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        anxietyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.anxietyBarID);
        anxietyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        painBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.painBarID);
        painBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        // end bars
        dPick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        tPick = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        noteField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteTextFieldID);
        enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButtonID);
    } catch (Exception onCreateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", onCreateException);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Bar listener methods
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int barValue, boolean hFromUser) {
    try {

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.happinessBarID:
            happyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.energyBarID:
            energyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.anxietyBarID:
            anxietyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.painBarID:
            painValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        }
        String debugBarValue = "Happy is " + happyValue + ", Energy is "
                + energyValue + ", Anxiety is " + anxietyValue
                + ", Pain is " + painValue + ".";
        System.out.println(debugBarValue);

    } catch (Exception BarValueException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", BarValueException);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// end Bar listener methods

// Enter Button listener Method

public void dialogPop(View v) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set Title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You entered: " + getMood())
                .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Okay",
                // When Okay button clicked the write mood string to file
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                try {
                                    // This is the string that should be
                                    // written to file
                                    String data = getMood();
                                    // This is the file that should be
                                    // written to
                                    File heapFile = new File("heapFile.csv");

                                    // if file doesn't exists, then create
                                    // it
                                    if (!heapFile.exists()) {
                                        heapFile.createNewFile();
                                    }

                                    // true = append file
                                    FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                            heapFile.getName(), true);
                                    BufferedWriter heapBufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(
                                            heapFileWritter);
                                    heapBufferWritter.write(data);
                                    heapBufferWritter.close();

                                    System.out.println("Done");

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        })
                // If they press either the cancel button or the back button
                // on their device (Same thing) then close the dialog and
                // give the user a chance to change what they've entered
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception buttonListenerException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", buttonListenerException);
    }
    return;
}

public String getMood() {
    try {
        int month = dPick.getMonth();
        int day = dPick.getDayOfMonth();
        int year = dPick.getYear();
        int minute = tPick.getCurrentMinute();
        String moodAntePost = "AM";
        boolean hourType = tPick.is24HourView();
        int moodHour = tPick.getCurrentHour();
        if (hourType == false && moodHour > 12) {
            moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
            moodAntePost = "PM";
        } else if (hourType == false && moodHour <= 0) {
            moodHour = 12;
        } else {
        }
        String noteText = noteField.getText().toString();
        Mood = "Happiness," + happyValue + ",Energy," + energyValue
                + ",Anxiety," + anxietyValue + ",Pain," + painValue
                + ",Date," + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ",Time,"
                + moodHour + ":" + minute + "," + moodAntePost + ",Note,"
                + noteText;
        System.out.println(Mood);
    } catch (Exception getMoodException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", getMoodException);
    }

    return Mood;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the XML code . i think there in  tag of your XML there is one attribute you have added android:onClick="enterMood".... try removing it and running it

use

android:onClick="dialogPop" instead

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have done the trick. Although now I'm getting exceptions because my file system is apparently read only but I think that might be because I forgot to tell the emulator to emulate actually having an sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler is not in the right format. It needs to include a view parameter for the XML click handler to work properly.

```
public void getMood(View view){

}
```